# Pandas read_html does not collect all tables from Wikipedia page

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, html-table, wikipedia

My goal is to write a parser that will collect ALL table data from a given wikipedia URL.
I've been trying to collect all tables from an example wikipedia page, using the pandas.read_html method. Unfortunatelly, it does not seem to collect all tables from the page. Here is my code:

`inputurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France"
        dflist = pd.read_html(inputurl, attrs={"class": "wikitable"})
        print("Number of parsed tables: ", len(dflist))
        for parsedtable in dflist:
            print("Collected table:")
            print(parsedtable )`

The issue is that returns only 2 tables, while there are more than 4 tables in this page. How can I improve the code to collect them all ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need remove `attrs`:

```
inputurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France"
dflist = pd.read_html(inputurl)
print("Number of parsed tables: ", len(dflist))
Number of parsed tables:  40
```

After check html code of page there are 3 tables with `class='wikitable'`, for third need specify both classes:

```
inputurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France"
dflist = pd.read_html(inputurl, attrs={"class": ["wikitable","wikitable sortable"]})
print("Number of parsed tables: ", len(dflist))
Number of parsed tables:  3
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly. May I have another question ? I would like to parse for each table the title of the paragraph just above the table and the text between the title of the paragraph and the table. For instance: Overseas territories and collectivities

In addition to the 18 regions and 101 departments [...]now use the euro.

Comment: @EmmanuelDaugeras - in pandas it is not possible, `read_html` only parse content in tag `<table>`, not html above it like `title`. Need `BeautifulSoup` for it.

Comment: Yes, but beautifulsoup is not so convenient to generate dataframes. Is there a way to match the beautifulsoup tags with pandas read_html dataframes ?

Comment: @EmmanuelDaugeras - No, pandas is only for data (tables), not for metadata (titles, paragraphs)